# implementing firebase anonymous auth on ios flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm looking at how to implement firebase anonymous auth on a flutter app. For android it works, but on the ios part it returns null.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the `Appdelegate.swift`. If any can show me a code sample on how to implement this firebase anonymous auth in this swift file for flutter it would be a lot of help.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

I found what was happening, on ios emulator the anonymous auth didnt work, it wasnt calling the method, on a pyshical device it worked